# background-image change button's default style in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I am making a numpad that run in Firefox.

Check fiddle example: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3HbFN/5/)    [ Open in Firefox]

My problem is, I tried to add a clear image like below:

[image]

I tried to add it to bottom right button, and it works for me,

But the problem is, the button's style and mouseon or click has been changed.

Just try to click other number button and feel the difference.

I am wondering, if there is a way just add pic to this button without destroy it's default
style.

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 755px; margin: 0 auto; ">
<div class="button-pad">
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="" />
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="" />
        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-pad">
        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="" />
        <input type="button" value="5" onclick="" />
        <input type="button" value="6" onclick="" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-pad">
        <input type="button" value="7" onclick="" />
        <input type="button" value="8" onclick="" />
        <input type="button" value="9" onclick="" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-pad">
        <input type="button" value="" />
        <input type="button" value="0" onclick="" />
        <input type="button" value="" onclick="" style="background-image:url(./img/clear.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button-pad > input{


color: #000000;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 15px;
width: 15%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use Icon Fonts in this case, that way you can add value to the button instead of adding background image:

here are some useful links:

http://fontawesome.io/

Edit: Replaced last input wit the button tag

```
   <button><i class=" icon-remove"></i></button>
```

and added icon font symbol inside
here's the demo too (with Font Awesome CSS included):

http://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/msnbd/

Comment: You are welcome, if you still  want to use type="button" here's how can you do that in a similar way http://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/93JSx/

Sorry forgot to mention here's the link where you can find other icons in unicode format 
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an input `type="button"` you could use a `<button />` and then put html like an `img` inside it.

```
<button value=""><img src="../img/clear.jpg" /></button>
```

or with a styled `div`

```
<button value=""><div style="background:url(../img/clear.jpg) no-repeat center center" /></button>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but can it possible to keep use type="button" ?

Comment: There isn't really any difference between input type="button" and button except button allows for html inside it, and hence is a bit more flexible.